# React native sending image to server using formdata

Tags: react-native, post

I have a problem sending a picture to a server, that's like the default approach, but it does not seem to work.

```
var source = '/Users/alexx/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/44F0FA92-4898-4CFB-862E-4E5EC4C8AB28/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/34BCE695-4B4F-472F-AB5C-F2336AC45273/DoorLock.app/123.jpg';
const form = new FormData();
form.append('image', {
  uri: source,
  type: 'image/jpg',
  name: '123.jpg',
});

const data = () => {
    fetch(api ,{
      method: 'POST',
      body: form,
    })
```

that's the response i get from the server:

```
{
  "_bodyBlob": {
    "_data": {
      "__collector": [
        Object
      ],
      "blobId": "78B18938-15BF-4F18-B3C8-1EB30A24D9F8",
      "name": "test.html",
      "offset": 0,
      "size": 192,
      "type": "text/html"
    }
  },
  "_bodyInit": {
    "_data": {
      "__collector": [
        Object
      ],
      "blobId": "78B18938-15BF-4F18-B3C8-1EB30A24D9F8",
      "name": "test.html",
      "offset": 0,
      "size": 192,
      "type": "text/html"
    }
  },
  "bodyUsed": false,
  "headers": {
    "map": {
      "connection": "keep-alive",
      "content-length": "192",
      "content-type": "text/html",
      "date": "Mon, 02 Nov 2020 22:57:21 GMT",
      "server": "PythonAnywhere"
    }
  },
  "ok": false,
  "status": 400,
  "statusText": undefined,
  "type": "default",
  "url": api
}
```

Although this python code works perfectly and gets a correct response

```
img = {'file':('123.png', open('the path to the pic/123.png', 'rb'), 'image/png)}
post(api, files = img)
```

is there any way to get this working or its the server side problem that can't receive the correct arguments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding "file://" to the beginning of the source string fixed the problem.
so the src looks like

```
var source = 'file:///Users/alexx/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/44F0FA92-4898-4CFB-862E-4E5EC4C8AB28/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/34BCE695-4B4F-472F-AB5C-F2336AC45273/DoorLock.app/123.jpg';
```

then it fetches perfectly, hope it helps anybody who tries to send a local image using formdata, the summary looks like this now

```
const form = new FormData();
      form.append('file', {
        uri: source,
        name: '123.jpg',
        fileName: 'file', //optional
      });

fetch(uri,{
             method: 'post',
             body: form,
      })
        .then(response => {
         console.log("image uploaded")
         console.log(response)
       })
        .catch(console.log);
```

Answer (score -1):

In Formdata when you pass files, you need to pass 3 parameters where

1. key expected from the backend (in your case `image`).
2. It will be an object which has three properties named `name`, `type`, and `uri` where type is the `mime type` (ex: `image/jpeg`).
3. name of the file

Eg:

> data.append("FilePath",{
> name:"image.png",
> type:"image/png",
> uri:"content://com.camera/image.png"
> },image.png)